# Show a function has the relationship as following

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

We have f: $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. Suppose $|f''(x)| \le 1 $ $\forall x \in[-1,1]$. Show that over [-1,1] we have:
$$|f(c+h)-f(c)-f'(c)h|\le \frac{h^2}{2}$$, for $c, c+h \in [-1,1]$.

I know that f is twice differentiable if all the partial derivatives up to and including order 2 exists and are continuous. The left side of the equation looks much like the first-order Taylor formula for approximating $f(c+h)-f(c)$ by $f'(c)h$. But I don't know how to derive the above relationship.

Comment: Is using partials really valid in this case since it is just a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The question is from a part of a problem, so the partials might not be used in this case. I'm just thinking if the twice differentiability of this function can be a useful fact.

Comment: Do you mean $|f''(x)| \le 1$? Otherwise $f(x)=-x^2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: If you make this amendment, you should be able to get the result by applying the mean value theorem to $f$.

Comment: Yes it's a typo, I mean $|f''(x)| \le 1$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis But if I apply the mean value theorem to $f$, I get $f(c+h)-f(c)=f'(a)h$, where $a \in (c,c+h)$, I'm still having trouble getting the inequality.

Comment: You can then bound $|f'(a)h - f'(c)h| < h|c-a|$ using $|f''|\le 1$. Using $|a-c|<h$ gives a bound of $h^2$ - improving this to $h^2/2$ is not immediately obvious, but probably involves a more precise estimate of the position of $a$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I'm bit confused about how you get $|f'(a)h-f'(x)h|<h|c-a|$. Is it since $|f''(a)|=\lim_{a\to c} |\frac {f'(a)-f(c)} {a-c}| \le 1$, then you get $|\frac {f'(a)-f(c)} {a-c}| \le 1$?

Comment: @Cjug: MVT again. $|f'(a)-f'(c)| = |f''(b)||a-c| \le |a-c|$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Not sure if the interval $x \in [-1,1]$ need to be included when using the MVT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Taylor: for every $c,c+h \in [-1,1]$
$$f(c+h)=f(c)+f'(c)h+\frac{f''(d)}{2}h^2$$
for some $d \in [c,c+h]$.
Now applying the modulus
$$|f(c+h)-f(c)-f'(c)h|=\frac{|f''(d)|}{2}h^2\le \frac{h^2}{2}$$
because $|f''(x)|\le1$ for every $x \in [-1,1]$.